# How do I access an object by index in a knockout observablearray?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array:

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Car", price: "9999" },
    { name: "Shoes", price: "20" },
    { name: "Paper", price: "1" }
]);
```

I'm trying to access the price of the first item in the array.

```
<div data-bind="text: myObservableArray()[0]"></div>
```

Displays:

```
[object Object]
```

I've tried:

```
<div data-bind="text: myObservableArray()[0].price"></div>
```

But that just returns a null.

What's the correct syntax for doing this?

Edit: Fixed a copy and paste error pointed out below.

Comment: That's how you do it. If it's not working, you have some other issue with your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than using the wrong property name, `developerexampledata` instead of `myObservableArray`, your code is just fine.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/GB4ae/)

Comment: Yeah that was a copy and paste error when I made the question, my bad. I appreciate the fiddle though; at least I know I've got the syntax right and my problem lay elsewhere. I'll accept your answer and dig in a bit more to figure out where else I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This could simply be down to you trying to access the first item of an array before the array has been populated.

Wrap your data-bind control with a simple if statement to check first:

```
<!-- ko if: (myObservableArray().length > 0) -->
    <div data-bind="text: myObservableArray()[0].price"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong way.....

```
self.getvaluefrom = function (a ,b)
```

try catch return a valid value
then add `data-bind="text:getvaluefrom(a,b)`
if the item is not in the array you'll get a ko error....

ko html displays only a static valid entry of an array....

Comment: Also   if you want to populate the array .... use var myarrayonload = function() alert("i loaded") its a private function .... then load what ever you want into the array....

Comment: var  onload = ko.computed(function()

Comment: no loops needed..... click: function    === self.onclick = function(data,event)    now use the var a = self.arrayentery.indexOf(data);